# Why Set UAC Execution level to asInvoker is not effect?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, uac

I've manifested a Visual Studio 2017 program to run `asInvoker`:

[image: Manifest Setting]

But when I run the compiled program: still requires elevation:

[image: generated program]

> Notice the **Shield** overlay

I've tried searching, but I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: "out program still need Administrator".  How could you tell?

Comment: Try to use another name for your executable, and it might then work. Windows unfortunately keeps a private name list for reserved words. And you also need to verify the compatibility database does not have a conflicting entry for your executable.

Answer (score -1):

Use a tool like [**Resource Hacker**](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to look at the `RT_MANIFEST` (id 24) assembly manifest resource:

[image]

If a manifest actually is correctly asking the OS to run the application `asInvoker`, then it's likely because the result of the elevation check is cached.

Try rebooting, or renaming the application to something else,e.g.:

> `PdfToWord - Testing renamed.exe`

But since this question was asked a month ago, i assume the problem has went away since then; so you can't really know if this fixed solved it.